# Android Canvas matrix

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, bitmap

For a school project I need to make a module to shrink a bitmap. So I made a matrix for this but when I draw directly the bitmap with the matrix like this :

```
canvas.drawBitmap(Bmp, ShrinkMatrice, p);
```

This work very fine, but I need to assign this matrix into the Bmp so I used a second canvas like this :

```
Canvas SuperCanvas = new Canvas(Bmp);
SuperCanvas.drawBitmap(Bmp, ShrinkMatrice, p);
```

but when I look the result with this :

```
canvas.drawBitmap(Bmp, 0,0, p);
```

the result look like this ( see the picture on the link ), the rest of the page is not draw correctly ...
if someone can explain me this problem :/...
Thank you in advance...
(Sorry if I made some error it's my first time on stackoverflow )

[image]

Comment: your matrix is probably wrong, but how to say without seeing it?

Comment: what is the goal of creating the `Canvas` with the specified `Bitmap` to draw into and drawing that `Bitmap` on itself?

Comment: No my matrix work fine because when i draw the bitmap with this matrix, this work fine but when i set the matrix on the bitmap before this not work...

I draw the bitmap in second time just for see if the matrix added well because the first canvas don't draw on the screen

Comment: just make an empty `Bitmap`, create a `new Canvas(emptyBitmap)` and finally draw your `Bitmap` on that `Canvas`, now you are drawing a `Bitmap` on itself

Comment: Oh okay i'm gonna try this !

Comment: Thank you very well, you save my life !! Thank you very much !! :D You are right !